# node.js start remote js file

Tags: node.js

is it possible node.js to start js files which are not located on the same machine where the node is started? (Something like node.exe http://myserver.com/app.js)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute the file locally you could [retrieve](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http.get) the remote file and then [execute](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_processes.html#child_process.spawn) it locally.

Otherwise you'll have to configure (probably by writing a script in Node, PHP, or whatever your preferred web scripting language is) the remote server to execute the file itself when you make a certain request. This has security implications, however—you'll need to take measures to protect against unauthorized requests using, say, HTTP basic authentication.

Comment: Ahh i see the principle. Thanks Jordan!

Answer (score 2):

You could also do something like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = 'url-to-js';
var script = '';
http.get(url, function(res) {
  res.on('data', function(d) {
    script+=d.toString();
  });
}).on('close', function(e) {
  eval(script);
});
```